# MacBook takes screenshots without user input

Tags: desktop, screen-capture, virus

Yesterday my desktop MacBook with Yosemite took a screenshot although I did not use that facility. It made the sound and created a file that I threw away fearing it was a virus. The doc created was not in fact a photo from the camera or the screen.

Today it happened again: the same sound of screen shot, but this time there is no file to be found in the computer.

Can this be a virus or an intruder?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Trend MICRO](https://www.trendmicro.com/vinfo/us/threat-encyclopedia/malware/osx_mokes.a) (September 12, 2016) the symptoms you describe do confirm that this could be a virus or intruder:

> Infection Channel: Downloaded from the Internet, Dropped by other malware
>
> > This backdoor enables the attacker to steal a range of information, including screenshots, audio, and keylogs. It can also execute commands and communicate using encrypted data.

Comment: Thank you. How can I clean my Mac and destroy this potential virus?

Comment: @EduardoTorres - You're Welcome :) By using antivirus software. Bitdefender was the best paid AV solution mid 2016 for Mac. Sophos came out second in terms of detection and performance, which is a free alternative. You can check AV-TEST for more up-to-date comparisons. Source: http://www.tomsguide.com/us/best-antivirus,review-2588-6.html